# Why does the confidence interval $(a(X), b(X))$ not depend on the parameter of interest?

Tags: confidence-interval

My notes in my textbook say that the confidence interval does not depend on the true value of our parameter of interest (say the mean). This seems counterintuitive to me as the distribution we see is characterised by the mean and variance. Surely if we had a different value for our parameter this would affect the outcome of our random interval.

If someone could explain my confusion I would be very grateful. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Your quotation states quite clearly that the endpoints depend "on the data" **and** constants. The data, of course, ultimately depend on the true parameter.

Comment: The first bullet point says the confidence interval depends only on the data X. This is what confuses me

Comment: It is often useful to look at mathematical formulas, because they are much clearer and more precise than English.  Pick any formula you like: does $\theta$ appear in it?

Comment: No, simply $X$ and some known constants. I have an example I have worked out that makes intuitive sense and I can see only known constants or $\hat{X_n}$. It is the sample mean estimating the population mean and then defining $Z$ under the standard normal. I have a more basic question if you would not mind indulging me, if I take say $n = 2$ observations from a sample. Those random variables, say $X_1$ and $X_2$, are they dependent on the population mean and variance?

Comment: "Dependent" is an overloaded term.  In the sense of "governed by," the answer is yes.  Intuitively, the two observed values give you information about the population they were drawn from.

Comment: Out of curiosity: From which book is this?